# count of sequences of array elements with appropriate sum

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Let us assume that we have an unsorted array of integers and 2 given integers L and M . Our task is to find the count of sequences a[i]...a[j] that hold the following property:   L<= a[i] + ... + a[j] <= M.

Which algorithm is the most appropriate to solve this problem?

Note:  1<=i<=j<=n  and the first element of array is a[1] ,not a[0].

Comment: it looks like case of segment tree.

Comment: Could these integers be negative?

Answer (score 2):

Provided that the integers are all non-negative, you could use this algorithm (pseudo-code):

```
countInRange(a, l, m):
    sumL = 0
    count = 0
    idxM = 0
    i = 1
    idxLast = len(a)
    for idxL = 1 to idxLast:
        sumL = sumL + a[idxL]
        while i <= idxLast and sumL >= l:
            if idxM <= idxL:
                idxM = idxL
                sumM = sumL
            while idxM <= idxLast and sumM <= m:
                idxM = idxM + 1
                if idxM > idxLast:
                    break
                sumM = sumM + a[idxM]
            count = count + idxM - idxL
            sumL = sumL - a[i]
            sumM = sumM - a[i]
            i = i + 1
    return count
```

This algorithm runs with *O(n)* time complexity:

In total, the inner-most loop will never iterate more than *n* times. This is because the value of *idxM* at entering the loop:

- is never lower than 1
- is never higher than *n*
- is always at least one greater than the previous time the loop was entered.

In total the middle loop will never execute more than *n* times either, as it increments *i* to *n*, and the same is clearly true for the outer loop.

See [this implementation in Python  on repl.it](https://repl.it/Dz1g/4) that also provides a *O(n²)* algorithm for retrieving the actual sequences themselves. Note though that that code had to be adapted to align with zero-indexed arrays in Python.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.The result though should be a number though .For example ,10 sequences ,12 sequences or something similar .We want to find the number of the sequences ,not the sequences themselves.

Comment: @user3697730 Just add counter and increment it in a proper place.of code

Comment: @user3697730, I updated my answer to only count. In that case the algorithm can run in *O(n)* time, which is not the case when the actual sequences need to be reported.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the following algorithm should do the job. I tried to implement it in JS. It's basically a single reduce operation with an initial value like `{idx:0, len:0, sum:0}` and there is a 3 level nested ternary inside.

For testing purposes I have generated an array of 30 items with random values between 1 - 10. Currently it gives the result as the series, for you to help me check if it's working well. Then as per your request the series counts, all we need is to replace the last

```
return r[0].sum < low ? r.slice(1) : r;
```

line with

```
return r[0].sum < low ? r.length-1 : r.length;
```

```js
function getLimitedSeries(a,low,high){
  var r = a.reduce((p,c,i) => (p[0].sum + c < low ? ( p[0].sum += c,
                                                      p[0].len++
                                                    )
                                                  : p[0].sum + c <= high ? ( p[0].sum += c,
                                                                             p[0].len++,
                                                                             p[0].idx = i-p[0].len+1
                                                                           )
                                                                         : ( p[0].sum >= low && p.push(p[0]),
                                                                             p[0] =  c > high ? {idx:i, len:0, sum:0}
                                                                                              : {idx:i, len:1, sum:c}
                                                                           ),p)
                              , [{idx:0, len:0, sum:0}]);  // initial value of reduce
  return r[0].sum < low ? r.slice(1) : r;
}

var arr = new Array(30).fill().map(e => ~~(Math.random()*10)+1);

console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
console.log(getLimitedSeries(arr,15,21));
```